# Can my custom method satisfy Pragma Warnings?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, pragma

For instance, when I do `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("")`, this satisfies the pragma warning:

> CS8604: Possible null reference argument

Now, if I had defined an extension method called `"".IsNull()`, would it be possible to somehow get the IDE/Compiler to recognizer it as a valid handler for CS8604?

```
public static bool IsNull(this string? s) => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you want one of the [attributes used by null-state static analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis).

In this particular case, I think you want `NotNullWhen`:

```cs
public static bool IsNull([NotNullWhen(false)] this string? s) => 
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s);
```

Comment: [DoesNotReturn] is also an excellent choice for methods used to wrap thrown exceptions.

Example:
[DoesNotReturn] private static void ThrowDependencyServiceException( string message, [CallerMemberName] string CallerMemberName = "" ) => throw new DependencyServiceException( $"{_className}.{CallerMemberName} {message}" );